# Delete git branch with -rD without deleting remote svn branch

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a local branch whose remote mirrors an svn branch. If I delete the local branch using git branch -D, will it physically delete the remote svn branch as well?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It will not `git branch -D <branch>` deletes the branch locally. Unless you do:

```
rm -rf .git/svn/refs/remotes/<branch>
```

the remote should remain intact.

Comment: Even that `rm ...` command won't actually affect the remote repository - just your local records of certain information from it...